# MPXJ is it possible to set % Complete of task? [version 5.1.10.0]

Tags: mpxj

I try to set 50 % Complete for single task using MPXJ in C# code

```
var pfTask = pf.GetTaskByID(new java.lang.Integer(task.ID));
pfTask.PercentageComplete = new java.lang.Integer(task.PercentComplete);
```

but it doesn't work - after opening in MS Project 2010/2013 50% is set but for **[% work Complete]** not for **[% Complete].**

Answer (score 0):

Try using the latest mpxj library. 5.2.2

Check these APIs of Task class
1. [setPercentageComplete](http://mpxj.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/sf/mpxj/Task.html#setPercentageComplete(java.lang.Number)) 
2. [setPercentageWorkComplete](http://mpxj.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/sf/mpxj/Task.html#setPercentageWorkComplete(java.lang.Number))